# Как хранить дату в MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

Работаю в Python. Мне нужно каким то образом записывать дату в MongoDB, что бы в дальнейшем делать выборку по этой дате. В каком формате и как лучше её хранить ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB поддерживает разные типы значений ([см. здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_datatype.htm)), в том числе `date` и `timestamp`. Таймстэмп подразумевается в UTC, поэтому следите за таймзоной. Пример записи с PyMongo:

```py
result = db.objects.insert_one(
    {"last_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
# Простой .now() не рекомендуется
```

Считывание:

```py
print([doc['last_modified'] for doc in db.objects.find()])
```

Вывод:

> [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 8, 18, 17, 28, 324000),
> datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 8, 11, 17, 42, 911000)]

Больше примеров и советов [в документации](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html).

Comment: А можно сделать так, что бы записывалось не время по UTC, а по GMT+3 ?

Comment: @lynx1 Вы можете записывать даты-время и в GMT+3, главное чтобы всё хранилось в одном часовом поясе, т.к инфа о таймзоне там не хранится, и 12 дня по Гринвичу и 12 дня по Москве будут записаны одинаково. Но лучше всё записывать и считывать в UTC, а там уже переводить в нужный себе часовой пояс, это стандартный подход.

Answer (score 0):

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

Даты в MongoDB хранятся как 64-битное число, составляющее количество миллисекунд начиная с эпохи Unix (1 января 1970г).

Чтобы лучше понимать как mongo хранит данные проще всего посмотреть [спецификацию BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html). Коротко и все по делу.